# Buy/Selling prices at the stock exchange represent someone Selling/Buying at that price?

Tags: stock-exchanges, financial-literacy, price

I see in my trading system two price quotes for a stock. Buying and Selling. Does the buying price means that it is the lowest price someone is currently attempting to sell their stock? If so, then does the selling price means it is the highest price someone is willing to buy that stock right now?

Is it then possible to drive a stock up or down by buying a large volume and then selling smaller chunks of it (or vise versa)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see Buying and Selling. You see Bid and Ask.

Best Bid--Highest Price someone is willing to pay to buy a stock.
Best Ask - Lowest price someone is willing to accept to sell a stock.

As for your second question, if you can look up Accumulation/Distribution Algorithm and Iceberg Order, you will get basic idea.

Comment: How does that work in the case where someone is selling 1000 shares, and someone is looking for 100? Does that averages 10 buyers looking for 100? Is there any kind of algorithm for cases like that? is it done in the Exchange level, or the Agent level?

Comment: If someone is selling 1000 and someone is buying 100, then in theory 100 shares will be sold and 100 will be bought. The next 900 shares will remain on the order book as a buy order, until a seller comes in. yes there are all kinds of sophisticated algorithms. If you google 'Order Matching algorithm' or 'Order Routing Algorithm', you will see some. The  order matching is done by an ECN/ATS like BATS or ARCA, which sits somewhere between the 'Agent'(market maker/broker-dealer) and the Exchange.

Comment: Are they all regulated tightly? Or they have some gray area to them?

Comment: I am sure there are grey areas like with any system, but the regulations are getting tighter and tighter.

Comment: Another related question: In Yahoo Finance, I see the price quote and then Bid and Ask. Those last two always change every few seconds. But the stock's price does not as often? Is the stock's quoted price is an average of sorts?

Comment: Nopes...the quoted price is the price at which the last trade was settled. So if buyer and seller cannot agree on a price, there is no trade and hence last traded price does not update as frequently. As for Bid and Ask, the MMs compete with each other, so they change frequently. The MM does so to always post the best Bid and Ask, so the trade actually happens, since MM makes money only when a trade happens. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, in some twisted way I can see how things function.

Comment: Yes, it is twisted in my opinion also.

Comment: Another one Q to clarify something from before: If I sell 1000 shares, and someone is interested to buy 100. You said in theory 100 are sold - 100 are bough - and 900 are back to the order book. But when I sell, the transaction is pending, until it is fully executed. I can cancel it any time while it is pending. What happens if someone bought a portion of my pending order? How does that work exactly? Sometimes I see on Yahoo Finance transactions for volume of 80k which translates to $100k+... How does this whole partial thing works? In my sale ticket I can choose All or None, what if I dont?

Comment: Oops you got me, i don't know this. At least in my broker's case, they don't allow cancelling the remaining sell order, but i think you should check with your broker.

Comment: OptionsHouse allows canceling partial orders, but you will have to pay additional commission fee if you chose to sell the remainder